# Долго грузится картинка

Tags: html

На сайте, если смотреть на показатель waterfall, картинка грузится 9-10 секунд, размер 2.4 мб, можно ли с этим что-то сделать и уменьшить время загрузки?

Comment: можно сжать её ..imageMin

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemin

Comment: Очевидно, нужно сделать размер меньше

Answer (score 1):

- уменьшить картинку
- использовать другой формат
- использовать альтернативный контент пока она грузиться
- показывать "загрузку.gif"
- не показывать сайт пока он полностью не загрузится
- разбить картинку на повторяющиеся элементы
- если у картинки больше половины это один цвет, использовать альфа канал для уменьшение замера (редкие случаи)
- и т.д.

также зависит от другого контента на сайте, если 2.4 mb это 90% сайта, для среднего интернет соеденения она должна грузиться 3-4 секунды.

Иначе средствами HTML - никак. Perl, PHP, Python, Ruby и др. - в теории да, при настройки общения между сервером.